# How can i reload element in angular2?

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I have three elements as mention below in angular HTML file

```
<element1></element1>
<element2></element2>
<element3></element3>
```

I want to reload element2 on execution of element2 component
How can I reload the content of element2?

Comment: What do u mean by `execution of element2 ` ? Is any function called on click ?

Comment: initially on page load, all three elements replace with there HTML content.but I want to reload element2 content every minute.

Answer (score 1):

To update a particular element every minute you need to set an interval inside of it.

For example let's say you want to update index of `element2` every minute, you can have a
function inside `setInterval` like below:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'element2',
    template: `
        <div>
        <h2>Element 2 Index {{index}}</h2>
        </div>
    `,
})
export class Element2 {
    index: number = 0;
    constructor() {
        // we need to pass interval in milliseconds
        // 1 minute = 60 seconds, 
        // 1 second = 1000 ms
        setInterval(() => { this.index++;}, 1000*60);
    }
}
```

Here I have taken the example of just updating the index, you can also update a list by making an API
call etc...

I have created a [plunker demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/B00ml3eSjYsmcZk8uX2l?p=preview) which updates
`element2` every **second**.